# Cannot buy via API due to the price always being zero

Tags: checkout, cart, soap, soap-api-v1

I have a fully working production site that I am trying to add API ordering to.

> I followed the sample here
>   http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.html

When I call `cart_payment.list` I only get back the "free" option

I add my item - which has a price - to the cart, and when I call `cart.totals` I get back

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Subtotal
        [amount] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Grand Total
        [amount] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Insured Shipping & Taxes
        [amount] => 25
    )
)
```

As the price is always zero, I can't submit the order with cart.order because I get a SOAP exception

> SoapFault exception: [1] amount must be greater than 0

If anyone has any ideas after 2 days of trying numerous samples and approaches and ending up with the exact same result whatever I do, I'd be grateful to hear them